# KernelBase.dll exceptions thrown while running C# dotnet 7 web app in IIS 10.0 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-applications

I created this web app in VS 2022, which uses only standard libraries.
Running in debugger mode on my laptop, it works without issue.

Published as In-Process, non-single file, format web deploy package.

Deployed to IIS, the app starts successfully and responds to initial HTTP POST commands properly, connects to SQL Express and inserts/reads records as expected.
Then start the exceptions from KernelBase.dll.

I tried:

1. Recreating the solution/project with the same source code
2. Reconfiguring IIS application pool
3. Delete and recreate the site
4. Installing VS 2022 on the server and attaching debugger to the IIS worker process

Check out these 2 shared files:

The full output of the debugger-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i4suAr84waXiMWqbJuJzfHJ1ReyClNGa/view?usp=sharing
A few lines I've observed:
Line 111 shows one exception after loading
Lines 305-306 state the web app was loaded successfully
Lines 311 and on, lots of exceptions until the patient dies.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sTIjKqVFW8YvYzG2d5ZeHuMg2_yX_8Fh/view?usp=sharing
This is a screen capture of VS2022 with the first exception, the stack trace and whatever other info that was provided.
In the stack trace, btw, it shows before the exception was thrown coreclr.dll code was executing.

Any suggestions on next steps?
Or does this look familiar to anyone?
Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have the wrong debugging engine active.  w3wp.exe is an unmanaged program, so the automatic selection is "native code".  But all the exceptions you got are C# exceptions.  In the attach dialog, click the Select button > "Debug these code types" radio button > pick the appropriate Managed engine.